# How to sort UCI machine learning datasets by number of hits?

Tags: machine-learning, web-scraping, dataset, data-mining

I want to find the most popular datasets. The home page of UCI Machine Learning site has the top 12 most viewed datasets. But, there seems to be no way to sort the datasets once you start browsing. The new beta site has a filter for sorting but it only takes into account hits on the new site.

[UCI old site](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php)

[UCI beta site](https://archive-beta.ics.uci.edu/)

Is there some way I can sort the datasets by number of hits? I want to find the top datasets for regression and classification. If not directly, can you help me with some script to sort the datasets?

Edit:
I used a web-**scraper** tool to get the required data. It worked for regression datasets but the site throws a memory error when tried with classification datasets. Likely due to there being more datasets in the classification category.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Comment: I am asking for a script. How's that not programming? If I knew how to do that, I would have.

Comment: Asking about a site's offered options is not a programming question; "*gimme a script that does this*" is not even a question. You are very welcome to post what you have tried so far, and request *programming* help on *specific* issues you may be facing. Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the current website doesn't have this functionality but the beta does. You can sort the full dataset list on the beta website based on the number of hits.

https://archive-beta.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets?&p%5Boffset%5D=0&p%5Blimit%5D=591&p%5BorderBy%5D=NumHits&p%5Border%5D=desc

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question, beta site hits are a fraction of the old site. This won't help with my need.